# TypeError: Modal is not a constructor - discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a modal system for my bot but this error keeps coming and I cannot fix it.

Here is my code:

```js
      const modal = new Modal()
      .setCustomId('MODALCREATION')
      .setTitle('Create a server')
      .addComponents([
      new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
       new TextInputComponent()
      .setCustomId('serverInvite')
            .setLabel("What is the server invite?")
            .setStyle('SHORT'),
        ),
     new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
       new TextInputComponent()
      .setCustomId('userId')
      .setLabel('Please enter the user ID:')
      .setStyle("SHORT"),
        )
      ])
      await i.showModal(modal)
```

Here is my error:

```js
TypeError: Modal is not a constructor
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/AwfulForsakenProfiles/index.js:1450:21)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Client.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/AwfulForsakenProfiles/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:73:12)
```

I defined all and stuff but nothing worked. On the discord guide it says the Modal in v13 not ModalBuilder so I don't know why it does not work.

My discord version is v13.4.0

[Guide](https://v13.discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html#building-and-responding-with-modals) i was talking about

Comment: What version of **DiscordJS** are you on, please check your **package.json**

Comment: Please, edit your question with a link to the guide you're using.

Comment: Done! My version is v13.4.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your **DiscordJS** version, according to this [`v13.7 change log`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/13.7.0) modals only into DiscordJS after **13.7**.

##### Update the Package

You can update to `13.7.0` by doing

```
npm install discord.js@13.7.0
```

However, I would advise you to either update to v14 or use `@13.12.0`